# Outputing a large file(>5GB) to a .zip archive in Java

Tags: java, jaxb, compression

I am trying to take a large, tab delimited .txt file that is around 6GB and turn it into a .xml file using the JAXB api.  This part works fine, but when I try to instead put that .xml into a .zip using ZipOutputStream, the .xml becomes corrupted when I try and look at it after(but it works for smaller files).

Is there another way I can do this or would it be better to do the the compression manually after the process runs?  Below is some of the code I am using when trying to make the .zip file.

```
IFSFile source = null;
IFSFileOutputStream target = null;
ZipOutputStream targetZip = null;

String targetName = "C:/test.zip";

source = new IFSFile(as400, sourceName);
BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new IFSFileReader(source));

target = new IFSFileOutputStream(as400, targetName, IFSFileOutputStream.SHARE_NONE, false);
targetZip = new ZipOutputStream(target);

ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("test.xml");
targetZip.putNextEntry(ze);

//JAXB stuff omitted, seems to be working as no problems with smaller files
while ((strRead = readBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
    currentRecord = new stuff;
    marshaller.marshal(currentRecord, targetZip);
}

targetZip.closeEntry();
targetZip.close();
readBuffer.close();
```

When looking for size limitations all I could find was that it would be corrupt if the .zp ended up larger than 4GB, which I don't think it will.  Am I doing something wrong or should I be using something other than ZipOutputStream for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) instead, it's part of java.util (so standard) and has better compression in (AFAIK) all cases, and will definitely handle files larger than 4Gb.

I think the ZipOutputStream might not be an implementation of ZIP64, if so it the original ZIP format has the 4Gb limit, as this is the maximum on a 32bit filesystem.

Comment: I've looked a little at the GZIPOutputStream, but it looks like that has to output to a .gz file format.  Do you need something special to open that format, or would something like 7zip be able to unpack it?

Comment: Yes 7zip will have no problem.  GZIP is a widely used opensource standard.

Comment: Do you know where I could find some good examples using GZIPOutputStream? I'm mainly a little confused on how it knows the file is .xml when it extracts it? Since the GZIPOutputStream doesn't seem to support the ZipEntry class that I was using to specify the name of the actual file.

Comment: This is for a single file, so it's just treated as a stream. If you name the file *.xml.gz then typically the unpacking tool will decompress and remove the trailing .gz

Answer (score 0):

I think 4gb is the limit set by java did u try java 7? I read this may be bug in java also.Please also check  [truezip](https://truezip.java.net/)

Comment: I thought 4GB was the limit for the .zip file.  Are you saying the limit is 4GB for the file before it gets compressed?